# What takes the most computing time in a monero wallet?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, source

What functions take up most of the time for a new or restored simplewallet?

Is it the scanning for its own inputs?

What code line does the most heavy lifting in the simplewallet codebase?

Lets say I restore a wallet from a block  14 days ago, what checks are performed, after I get all the blocks and pruned tx data, that take most of the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two main operations in terms of CPU usage are determining if an output is sent to you (is_out_to_acc_precomp, defined in src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_format_utils.cpp) and generating the key derivations that is_out_to_acc_precomp acts on (generate_key_derivation, defined in src/crypto/crypto.cpp). There is some threading there, but it could still be sped up.

Both of those end up calling low level crypto functions, such that a profile looks like this:

```
  18.00%  monero-wallet-cli          [.] fe_sq
  17.54%  monero-wallet-cli          [.] fe_cmov
   3.21%  monero-wallet-cli          [.] fe_invert
   3.08%  monero-wallet-cli          [.] fe_divpowm1
   2.86%  monero-wallet-cli          [.] fe_sq2
   2.35%  monero-wallet-cli          [.] fe_add
   1.75%  monero-wallet-cli          [.] select
   1.62%  monero-wallet-cli          [.] keccakf
   1.16%  monero-wallet-cli          [.] ge_p2_dbl
   0.97%  monero-wallet-cli          [.] ge_scalarmult_base
   0.80%  monero-wallet-cli          [.] ge_scalarmult
```

There are a couple asm versions of those, which proved to give some substantial speedup too, see https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/2317

Answer (score 1):

Without profiling, I would guess `void wallet2::process_new_transaction` ([link](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/13a34faeb09814121140e14e0af442714fa985f9/src/wallet/wallet2.cpp#L1217)) or by virtue of it being called, one of it's ancestors. This is because an incoming block has to have it's transactions scanned.

Of course, only profiling can confirm this guess.